# SharePoint 2013 Foundation Site Translation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, language, machine-translation

I have a SharePoint site that is going to be used by german and french speaking users. They are going to be using one account or maybe two for the same site if it is not possible with a single user. I know how to change the interface of the UI but I have a lot of custom created lists and libraries with custom columns. All of the lists, libraries and columns need to be shown or translated in another language. The site is created in german language including the content of the site. French speaking users want to view the site in their language including the list/library names and their columns. Is there a way to achieve that either with apps or custom solutions?

Kind regards